# looking for japanese speech to hiragana text programs

Tags: discussion

I'm looking to convert spoken japanese into hiragana as opposed to the standard written forms. microsoft's speech sdk doesn't seem to have this feature, so I was wondering if there are any other programs out there with this option. Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: You mean speech recognition? What is the purpose for it? I don't think any present speech recognition technology for any language will be capable for serious practical use. They are just toys at the moment. Maybe use can ask the same question come decades later for some useful answers.

Comment: yes though it seems like standard speech recognition only goes from speech to hiragana+kanji+katakana mix. I just want to go pure hiragana

Comment: Hiragana is phonology writing system so you can just manually type what you hear; unlike English - oh why do I still remember that time when I was doing English listening test and I couldn't decide whether it's "peace of mind" or "piece of mine"?

Comment: @mugetsu: I don't know much about Japanese, but if there's software for speech to hiragana+kanji+katakana (and that's a big if), couldn't you pipe that output into something that converts kanji and katakana into hiragana?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm http://www.romaji.org/ I found my own answer lol.

Comment: http://kakasi.namazu.org/ even better, a perl module

Comment: I think this question belongs on Super User. It's not a question aobut the JL&U site.

Comment: How about Julius ( http://julius.sourceforge.jp/ ), a speach recognition decoder engine for japanese.